# Why should we handle errors in the code when Ruby will do it for you?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

Why would we need to handle errors given that if an error occurs, Ruby will tell you? What is the point of us writing it in code?

When I write code and Ruby doesn't like it, it will tell me with the error type.

Answer (score 1):

When ruby throws an error, it basically explodes. As Sergio mentions - this means your user gets an ugly error message instead of your nice application's interface.

In that case, we want to catch the error and show a useful message to the user eg "this is what went wrong, to fix it please do this..." A good example is when a user accidentally forgets to fill in a mandatory field. Your app could explode, or you could show a nice message to them saying "please fill in the address field"

in some cases the error isn't really that bad - and you can just do something else instead. Eg if you're updating 5000 things and they're not super-important... so if one fails, you just silently catch the error, write a log-message about it... and move onto the other 4999

Sometimes an error is thrown because the user is doing something naughty - eg trying to access something they shouldn't. In that case, if your app explodes with the error message, you're giving away what could be potentially security-unsafe information (they try various things and see what error messages come back). In that case, you want to catch the error and display some non-descript information to them instead.

So... you add handlers to deal with known situations and make the user experience less nasty.

Comment: Yes. I thought, "user errors must be handled" - this is obvious. Thanks for elaborating on this :)

Comment: Wow taryn that was an awesome answer and very easy to understand. I guess my problem is that Im using Ruby in Chef for now and when a,chef run errors out we didn't need to catch errors. I am planning to learn more about using ruby outside of Chef to build apps and your answer was perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 it will tell me with the error type
```

This means your program has crashed and it can't do anything useful anymore, because it's not running. Easy for a programmer to fix, but very annoying for users, because they can't fix it. Leave a couple of these and you'll be the only user of your program.